# Синхронизация потоков в java для вычислений и вывода информации на график в режиме реального времени

Tags: java, многопоточность, javafx, java-timertask

Получаю с COM-порта показания с Arduino. После нажатия кнопки "Старт" в течении 30 секунд нужно считывать информацию, выводить значение на график и считать интеграл.

Сейчас все написано на потоках с использованием интерфейса Runnable и флага.
В одном потоке происходит чтение и вычисления, в другом вывод на график, в третьем контроль времени чтения и управление флагом.

Проблема заключается в том, что ввиду особенностей информации вывод на график начинается раньше, чем получение корректных данных. Поэтому хотелось бы узнать, при помощи каких инструментов можно исправить данную ситуацию. Либо может вообще стоит использовать другие средства для организации многопоточности для данной задачи.

1. Запускаю поток чтения информации, который открывает порт и ждет установки флага

   ```
   private void dataReading(){        
   Runnable readTask=()->{
       try {
           readPort.openPort();
           readPort.setParams(SerialPort.BAUDRATE_19200, 
           SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

           while (cont) {
               try{
                   byte n=(byte)(firstByte[0]>>6);
                   while (n!=0) {
                       firstByte=readPort.readBytes(1);
                       n = (byte)(firstByte[0]>>6);
                   }
                   byte[] buffer = readPort.readBytes(3);
                   //обработка
                   }
               catch (Exception e){}
           }
       }
       catch (Exception e){};
   };
   Thread readThread = new Thread(readTask);
   readThread.start();
   }
   ```
2. Запускаю поток вывода информации, который начинает вывод по факту остановки флага

   ```
   private void dataOutput(){

   XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series<>();
   weightChart.getData().addAll(series1);

   Runnable paintTask=()->{
       int i=0;
       while (cont){
               XYChart.Data data = new XYChart.Data(i++, dataPoint);
               Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                       if (dataPoint!=0)
                           series1.getData().add(data);
                   }
               });
               try {
                   Thread.sleep(20);
               } catch (Exception e) {}
               ;
           }
   };

   Thread paintThread = new Thread(paintTask);
   paintThread.start();
   }
   ```
3. Устанавливаю флаг, включаю таймер, который срабатывает через 30 секунд и сбрасывает флаг.

   ```
   private void buttonsOnOff(){

   startW1.setDisable(true);
   startW2.setDisable(true);

   Timer squatTimer=new Timer();
   TimerTask squatTimerTask=new TimerTask() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           try {
               startW1.setDisable(false);
               startW2.setDisable(false);
               //readPort.closePort();
               squatTimer.cancel();
               cont=false;
           }
           catch(Exception e){};
       }
   };

   cont=true;
   squatTimer.schedule(squatTimerTask,30000);
   }
   ```

Так как цельный участок данных составляет 4 байта, зачастую приходится пропускать некоторое количество байт, чтобы найти первый из четверки. А вывод информации стартует сразу же. Если запускать поток вывода после получения первого байта, то график перестает обновляться.

Comment: что-то не очень ясно что делается на самом деле. Как у Вас потоки координируеются между собой и через что обмениваются информацией? Наверное бы смотрел в сторону алгоритма в котором один поток пишет в какую-то очередь. а второй оттуда забирает. Код в таком случае должен быть намного проще

Comment: Да, упустила. Есть переменная dataPoint, которая обновляется в потоке dataReading, там где //обработка. Она и выводится раз в 20мс. То есть как бы просто раз в 20мс поток вывода берет текущее значение этой переменной.

Comment: так нужен кусок кода с этой переменной - потому что не ясно как синхронизируется - вместе с элементами синхронизации потоков которые используются